# No results with PHP search in MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a database where I store DNS logs. The data is stored in the collection `dnslog`. This is the document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53539df1e4b076aa8975840a"), 
    "dateandtime" : ISODate("2014-04-09T03:42:48Z"), 
    "client" : "222.29.72.224", 
    "query" : "www.google.com", 
    "other" : "AAAA"
}
```

I stored nearly a week's log into the database and the total count is 821943936;
I have the following PHP script to search for results:

```
$m = new MongoClient();
echo "Connection to database successfully"."<br />";
$db = $m->dns;
echo "Datebase dns selected"."<br />";
$collection = $db->dnslog;
echo "Collection selected succsessfully"."<br />";
$startdate = new MongoDate("2014-04-09 11:42:00");
$enddate = new MongoDate("2014-04-09 11:43:00");
$result = $collection->find(array("dateandtime"=>array('$gte'=>$startdate,'$lte'=>$enddate)));
echo $result->count();
foreach($result as $doc){
      echo $doc['client']."<br />";
}
```

The script does not return any results. This is the output from the script.

```
Connection to database successfully
Datebase dns selected
Collection selected succsessfully
```

I'm sure that in that I have documents for the specified query because I can see the document when I use:

```
db.dnslog.find();
```

Comment: note: where's the error handling? `successfully` lol.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong. [MongoDate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php) is expecting UNIX timestamp as parameter in the constructor:

```
$startdate = new MongoDate(strtotime("2014-04-09 11:42:00"));
$enddate = new MongoDate(strtotime("2014-04-09 11:43:00"));
```

Comment: I found that, when the records in the collections up to 100 million, there is no results returns for the $result = $collection->find(), but the records is about 3 million, it still can return result